# Paste format only in Google Spreadsheets with Chrome as the browser

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

I want a working keyboard shortcut for Google Spreadsheets, that lets me paste just the formatting. [Google says](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/179738?hl=en) the shortcut for copying just the formatting is <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and pasting just the formatting is <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

However, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> opens up the Chrome Dev Tools panel. And, perhaps because of this, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> doesn't do anything. I don't actually think the "copy just format" is necessary -- you only need the special paste functionality. But using the standard <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy a cell and then trying <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> doesn't do anything.

The "Paint Format" button also does what I want, but there is no keyboard shortcut for that.

I would be happy to create a custom Chrome extension to achieve this, but my initial attempt (simply trigger a click event on the corresponding menu item element) didn't work -- not for paste format nor paint format.

Looking for any kind of solution that ultimately lets me use a keyboard shortcut to paste cell formatting.

Answer (score 17):

<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> then,

<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>

works for me on a Mac.

---

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> then,

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

works on Windows

Answer (score 3):

Copying with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and pasting with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> then <kbd>s</kbd> then <kbd>f</kbd> works for me.

But as you are typing <kbd>Cmd</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> maybe you're on a Mac, aren't you? I don't know if this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I mapped it to <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> here. You can change it withing the AHK script below. I have set the shortcut to specifically work on Chrome so it won't interfere with any other programs.

Use the following autohotkey script:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
;SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
;keyWait waits for a user to physically release a key, so don't use
#NoTrayIcon
#Persistent
#SingleInstance Force


#IfWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
!z::     ; ALT+Z
Send, {alt down}e
sleep, 50
send, s
Sleep, 50
send, t
send, {alt up}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old & has been answered, but just to confirm that as of 2018.07.28, double-clicking on the Paste Format button still does not work as expected (allowing multiple Format Pastes).  What does work is:

- **L.Click** the Cell you want to adopt the format of (Origin)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- **L.Click** the Cell you want to receive the adopted formatting (Recipient)
- Press&Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, PRESS DON'T HOLD <kbd>Alt</kbd>, Press&Hold <kbd>V</kbd>

And that's it.  Also works for any arbitrary number of other cells (at step 3, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+**L.Click** as many Cells as you wish; probably <kbd>Shift</kbd>+**L.Click** works as well).  Also, the "Press Don't Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>" bit seems to work for Step 2 as well, for some reason.

Answer (score -2):

(windows) in google sheets after <kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> your desired formatting - you have to hold down 
<kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd> first, then press <kbd>v</kbd> to paste/paint it to the new cells

or

(windows) in google sheets copy cells with the desired formatting using: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> 
then highlight cells you wish to paint the formatting to & press:
<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> then <kbd>s</kbd> then <kbd>t</kbd>

Answer (score -2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

It helps me. Chears.